# AngularJS view not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make my first AngularJS application and I've run into a problem.

I have an input:

```
<input ng-model="userNameLogin" type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
```

A button:

```
<button ng-click="setActiveUser()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
```

and an expression:

```
{{ activeUser }}
```

I want the text to change to whatever was typed in the input once the button is clicked. For that I have the following controller:

```
app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.userNameLogin = "";
    $scope.activeUser = "Test";

    $scope.setActiveUser = function() {
        $scope.activeUser = $scope.userNameLogin;
        console.log($scope.activeUser);
    };
}]);
```

The initial value "Test" is shown just fine and according to the console the value of "activeUser" is being changed correctly as well. But the text in the view stays the same.

I have seen similar questions where a `$scope.$apply()` was the answer, but if I add that after the `console.log` I get

> "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress".

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I have noticed that If I put the input, button and expression in the same HTML file it all works fine. However my Input and button are in a navbar in `index.html` while the expression is in `view1.html`

This is the body of `index.html`:

```
    <body ng-app="myApp.view1">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="View1Ctrl as view">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/view1">Kwetter</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#/view1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/view2">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="userNameLogin" type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button ng-click="setActiveUser()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="pagewrapper" class="container">

    <div ng-view></div>

    <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>
</div>
```

and this is my `view1.html`

```
    <div ng-controller="View1Ctrl as view">
<!-- row 1: welcome -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 pull-left">
        <image ng-src="{{ view.users[0].avatar }}"/>
        <!-- If I put the button and input here it will work -->
        <input ng-model="userNameLogin" type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
        <button ng-click="setActiveUser()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        {{ activeUser }}
    </div> 
</div>
<!-- row 2: main content -->
<!-- left the rest of the content out because it would just clutter the page -->
```

I tried placing the `ng-controller` in `<div id="pagewrapper" class="container">` instead of the first div of `view1.html`, but that made no difference.

Comment: may be you have placed `{{ activeUser }}` outside of controller div

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, pankajparker. I checked and this is not the case.

Comment: Ben Felda, by "the text stays the same" I mean that it says "Test", even after the button is clicked.

Comment: Is the console showing you what you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, If I would type "Berry" in the input box, the console would say "Berry", as is intended.

Comment: I just ran this your code as is and it worked fine,  I'll tend to agree with the frist comment and say that {{ activeUser }} isn't within the element where you defined ng-controller="View1Ctrl"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my navbar (containing the input and button) in a partial and made a new directive for it. Instead of placing the navbar in the `index.html` I put it in the individual partials and now it works fine. I suspect the problem had something to do with different scopes.

navbar html:

```
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/view1">
            Kwetter
            <image id="navbar-image" src="src/kwetter_logo.png"/>                    
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#/view1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/view2">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="userNameLogin" type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button ng-click="setActiveUser()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

the directive:

```
    app.directive('navbar', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/navbar.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl as view'
}
```

});

Then I just added `<navbar></navbar>` to every view where I want a navbar.
Thanks everyone, your help pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I think u have misplaced the button or textbox or expression, 
note : these should be inside the ng-controller. 
please try this, it will work

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
      <input ng-model="userNameLogin" type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
      <button ng-click="setActiveUser()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      {{activeUser}}
    </div>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js code

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);


app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.userNameLogin = "";
    $scope.activeUser = "Test";

    $scope.setActiveUser = function() {
        $scope.activeUser = $scope.userNameLogin;
        console.log($scope.activeUser);
    };
}]);
```

refer http://plnkr.co/edit/ixbByBQ9nGm4XEqEFi4t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have the properties directly on `$scope` and that is breaking the binding.  Instead try:

```
app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.userInfo = {
        userNameLogin: "",
        activeUser:"Test"
    }
    $scope.setActiveUser = function() {
        $scope.uesrInfo.activeUser = $scope.userInfo.userNameLogin;
        console.log($scope.activeUser);
    };
}]);
```

and in your view:
`{{userInfo.activeUser}}`

From Egghead.io https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Answer (score 0):

Within your code I can't see anything causing the problem. I made a fiddle, that shows that your code works:

http://jsfiddle.net/xxvsn8xs/

You need to declare the `ng-app`and the `ng-controller` of course, like in the fiddle, to let the app work at all.

Also, an view update might not occur, if setting the activeUser actually occurs outside of the angular scope, which might be within an external library or whatever. It is true, that these could be achieved by calling $scope.$apply() directly, but it is nor recommended, as the digest might already be in progress. This is the case in your code, as why you get the according error message.

Instead use angulars `$timeout` service with a callback and 0 delay, that applies the value to `$scope.activeUser`. `$timeout` will check, if a digest cycle is in progress and if not, will start one.

```
$scope.setActiveUser = function() {
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.activeUser = $scope.userNameLogin;
    console.log($scope.activeUser);
  });
};
```

Don't forget to define `$timeout` in your controllers dependencies:

```
 app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular watches the variable you bind to `$scope`, but if you replace that variable Angular is not able to detect it. That's why `$apply` would be a suggestion.

Another suggestion is to bind the variable to a 'model' variable:

```
app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.userNameLogin = "";
    $scope.myData = { activeUser: "Test" };

    $scope.setActiveUser = function() {
        // Angular will pick up the change in the myData object, and will update all variables attached to it
        $scope.myData.activeUser = $scope.userNameLogin; 
        console.log($scope.myData.activeUser);
    };
}]);
```

view:

```
{{ myData.activeUser }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute your application in Apache ? I'd the same issue when I was using file:// And I fixed my issue by using a localhost.